# Library can only be accessed using SUDO - libfprint permissions

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sudo, fingerprint, printf

I have downloaded and installed the [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint) fingerprint API. Everything works ok but there is one snag, it will only detect my fingerprint scanner when I run applications using sudo.

This is puzzling because I have libfprint on another machine which works fine without sudo (maybe version 0.5).

Anyhow, I have no option but to develop on this current machine (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit). The problem is that I am developing an application which uses the library in Eclipse. This means I have to run Eclipse as Sudo which I am aware is a bad idea. **Does anybody know how I can make the library accessible without being root?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121202125953/https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint#Permissions). Hope this helps somebody !